# UnicodeWarning fired only once

Tags: python, unicode, internals

Consider:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> 'abc' == u'abc'
True

>>> 'ab\xDF' == u'abc'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False

>>> 'ab\xDF' == u'abc'
False
```

Why isn't the warning fired for the second time? I guess this has something to do with interning, but can't figure out what exactly.

I'd appreciate a cpython-source level explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default configuration for Python is to use the [`default` warning configuration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) (with a [few specific exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filters)). This means that warnings are emitted just once *per warning, module and line*.

See the [`-W arg` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W):

> By default, each warning is printed once for each source line where it occurs.

The `UnicodeWarning` will be emitted again if the same comparison problem arises in a different module or line number.

In the interactive interpreter, every time you enter some code that block starts with line number 1 again, and are always executed in the `__main__` module. So the second time you ran the comparison, the code ran as line 1 in the `__main__` module *again*, so the warning was suppressed.

If you triggered the issue in a different module, or on different lines, you'd see the warning again:

```
>>> 'ab\xDF' == u'abc'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
>>> 'ab\xDF' == u'abc'
False
>>> if True:
...     'ab\xDF' == u'abc'
... 
__main__:2: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

The second comparison was on line 1 again, so the warning was suppressed, but by adding `if True:` before the comparison we got two lines and the warning was emitted again.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that there is 'once' value for attribute 'action' for UnicodeWarning:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Comment: It's actually `default`, not `once`.

Comment: Which module do you mean?

Comment: The OP ran the code in the `__main__` module (all code in the interactive interpreter does). If they created a new module and triggered the same issue, that'd result in the warning being displayed again as that's in a different module. If they triggered the issue on separate lines in that module, you'd get warnings for each of those lines.

Comment: There is no separate configuration for the `UnicodeWarning`.